# Is there a way to show shortcuts in Windows in a different color?

Tags: windows, microsoft-file-explorer

this is a Windows related question.

I would like to see the shortcut (files) in Windows File Explorer with a different color. So that it would not be necessary to have a " - Shortcut " suffix at the end of the file name and it would be quickly obvious that it's a shortcut. We have "type" column which states it's a shortcut but you need an extra eye movement to check that :)

For example: Linux command line interface can show shortcuts in a different color, by default *cyan*.

[image]

Can this be done in Windows, in File Explorer?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, only compressed and encrypted files [can](https://superuser.com/questions/1104886/encrypted-files-in-win10-explorer-does-not-show-in-green-anymore) be displayed in different colors by Explorer/`IShellView`.

Several of the 3rd-party Explorer replacements lets you customize colors based on the file extension etc.